# SFTP Connection Issue "Connection reset by peer"

Tags: ftp, sftp

I am unable to connect to Secured FTP server Using Filezilla and psfTP too.
While connecting one popup message comes for Certification, then I find this error

Error Message:--
Status: Connecting to idx.XYZ.com...
Response:    fzSftp started
Command:    open "abc_mnp@idx.XYZ.com" 22
Command:    Pass: **********
**Error:    Network error: Connection reset by peer
Error:  Could not connect to server**

Any Idea guys..
I feel this is an Issue with Server.